# Disable pause function on click Fotorama slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

Check live- http://www.arif-khan.net/other/my/slider/new/v3/

If you click on slideshow it pauses, i want to turn-off that functionality. Tried with `data-click="false"` but no luck.

Slider created with Fotorama(http://fotorama.io/), already check all documentation(customization) on that site but don't get any info that fix my problem. I will want to disable pause on click on slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `data-stopautoplayontouch="false"`. It should work.